# Why my Theorems, Lemmas and ... are represented without caption?

Tags: captions

I have this comment up my document

```
\documentclass[aoas,preprint]{imsart} 
\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\RequirePackage{amsthm,amsmath} 
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}  
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyp‌​erref}  
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{cite} 
\arxiv{arXiv:0000.0000} 

\startlocaldefs
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[thm]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[thm]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[thm]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[thm]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[thm]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[thm]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[thm]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[thm]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[thm]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[thm]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[thm]{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[thm]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[thm]{Summary}
\endlocaldefs
```

Why my Theorems, Lemmas and ... are represented without caption?

Comment: Your code sniped doesn't indicate which theorem style you use.

Comment: please say me, the proper code. @Zarko

Comment: Please tell us how the macros `\startlocaldefs` and `\endlocaldefs` are defined, please tell us whether you use a theorem-related package (e.g., `ntheorem` or `amsthm`), and please provide one or two examples of code of theorem-like environments that do not show numbers.

Comment: I am new user of latex. I do not know your questions answer. the following codes are up my sample file:
\documentclass[aoas,preprint]{imsart}
\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cite}
\arxiv{arXiv:0000.0000}

\startlocaldefs
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\endlocaldefs @Mico

Comment: You seem to be using SWP. Forget it, at least when preparing documents for submissions. The SWP specific part will ***greatly*** annoy the copy editors (direct experience).

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes you right, I used to SWP. But unfortunately there is very little education source for Latex in my language and my English language is not well. @egreg

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Please clarify what you mean by "Why my Theorems, Lemmas and ... are represented without caption". For sure, as the following example demonstrates, the theorem-like environments are given labels such as "Theorem" and "Acknowledgment".

Incidentally, you shouldn't load both the `natbib` and the `cite` packages. Load one or the other, but not both.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aoas,preprint]{imsart} % defines the macros "\startlocaldefs" and "\endlocaldefs"
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath} 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{float} 
%%%\usepackage{cite} % don't load both 'natbib' and 'cite'
\arxiv{arXiv:0000.0000} 
%\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyp‌​erref} 

\startlocaldefs 
\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
\theoremstyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[thm]{Acknowledgement}
\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example

\begin{thm}[Trivial]
$1+1=2$.
\end{thm}

\begin{acknowledgement}[Effusive]
Many thanks to everyone.
\end{acknowledgement}

\end{document}
```